# "Point added" event, while drawing polygon with google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

Is there a way to listen on click event, while drawing polygon with google maps api, or even better event which is fired when user added another point into polygon.

I can listen on these two events: `polygoncomplete`, `overlaycomplete`, which are fired only when polygon is completed.

Here in docs: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/drawinglayer
it says: `Note that google.maps.Map events, such as click and mousemove are disabled while drawing on the map.`

What I want to achieve is demonstrated In this picture:
https://mrkr.io/ImzbFZSTOr

On first click with polygon tool I'd like to put there marker and tooltip about what to do. On next click I'd remove tooltip and change style of markers. And on all subsequent clicks also. As it's in the picture.

If there's no way to listen to such event, do you have any suggestions how to achieve this?

Thank you very much for any kind of help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the onClick listener on the Google Map is disable, but you can still listen to the dom's onClick just like this:

```
$(document).click(function() {
    document.getElementById("count").innerHTML = ++i;
});
```

I have a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kylelam/mjdhtos8/) demoing this, hope this help.

Also, you can look at [this blog](http://ben-bai.blogspot.com/2012/12/convert-mouse-position-to-latlng-in.html) for converting mouse position to Lat/Lng.

Comment: I am getting this event but how to get longitude, latitude of that point ?

Comment: the blog linked above suggested to convert mouse x, y to lat, long